# If $R$ is an integral domain then $\text{Tor}(M)$ is a submodule of $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, modules

**Question**:

An element $m$ of the $R$-module $M$ is called a torsion element if $rm = 0$ for some nonzero $r \in R$.  The set of torsion elements is denoted

$$
\text{Tor}(M) = \{m \in M : rm = 0 \thinspace \text{for some nonzero}\thinspace  r \in R\}.
$$

(a) Prove that if $R$ is an integral domain then $\text{Tor}(M)$ is a submodule of $M$.

(b) Give an example of a ring $R$ and an $R$-module $M$ such that $\text{Tor}(M)$ is not a submodule.

(c) If $R$ has zero divisors show that every nonzero $R$-module has nonzero torsion elements.

**My Attempt**:

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $M$ be an $R$-module.  We will use the Submodule Criterion to show that $\text{Tor}(M)$ is a submodule of $M$.  Since $(M, +)$ is an abelian group there exists the zero-element $0 \in M$ and for any nonzero $r \in R$ one has that $r0 = 0$.  Hence $0 \in \text{Tor}(M)$ and we see that $\text{Tor}(M)$ is nonempty.  Now suppose that $x,y \in \text{Tor}(M)$ and let $r$ be any element from $R$.  To finish the proof we need to show that $x + ry \in \text{Tor}(M)$.  Since $x,y \in \text{Tor}(M)$ there exists nonzero $s_1$ and $s_2$ in $R$ such that $s_1x = s_2y = 0$, so consider the ring element $s_1s_2$.  We assume that $R$ is an integral domain, so since neither $s_1$ nor $s_2$ are equal to 0 their product $s_1s_2$ is not equal to 0.  Then we have

$$
s_1s_2(x + ry) = (s_1s_2)x + (s_1s_2)ry = s_2(s_1x) + s_1r(s_2y) = s_2(0) + s_1r(0) = 0,
$$

since $R$ is an integral domain (multiplication is commutative in the ring).  This equality shows that $x + ry \in \text{Tor}(M)$ and we conclude that $\text{Tor}(M)$ is in fact a submodule of $M$, proving (a).  To prove (b), consider the ring $R = \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the set of matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ and set $M = R$ (every ring $R$ is an $R$-module over itself).  If we let

$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
y = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$

then

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

show that there are nonzero elements in $R$ which when multiplied to $x$ and $y$ give the zero element in $R$.  In other words, $x, y \in \text{Tor}(M)$.  However, note that

$$
x + y = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$

and if

$$
r = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is any matrix in $R$, then

$$
r(x + y) = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
b & a \\
d & c
\end{pmatrix},
$$

so $r(x + y)$ is the zero matrix only when $a = b = c = d = 0$.  In other words, there is no nonzero element in $r \in R$ which satisfies $r(x + y) = 0$, hence $x + y \notin \text{Tor}(M)$.  This counterexample proves that $\text{Tor}(M)$ fails the submodule criterion and therefore $\text{Tor}(M)$ is not a submodule of $M$, proving (b).  For (c), suppose that $R$ is a ring which has nonzero zero divisors and let $M$ be any nonzero $R$-module.  Let $a$ and $b$ be two nonzero zero divisors in $R$, so that $ab = 0$.  Suppose by way of contradiction that the only torsion element of $M$ is $0 \in M$.  This means that if $m \in M$ is nonzero, $rm \neq 0$ for every nonzero $r$.  In particular, $b \neq 0$ gives that $bm \neq 0$, and if $bm$ is a nonzero element of $M$ then also $a(bm) \neq 0$.  But

$$
a(bm) = (ab)m = 0m = 0,
$$

thereby giving a contradiction.  Because of the contradiction, our initial assumption was incorrect - there must be torsion elements in $M$ which are nonzero thus proving (c).

Comment: Your solution is correct, and perfectly well written. Well done! :)